# PPT does not open in LiberOffice Impress

Tags: libreoffice

I am unable to edit a ppt file created on Microsoft in LibreOffice Impress Version: 4.2.3.3
Build ID: 420m0(Build:3)

The presentation gets completely distorted. Am I missing any patch on LibreOffice?

Answer (score 1):

That's a common issue. The import of Microsoft Office documents in LibreOffice is far from perfect (notably because Microsoft uses or used to use obscure file formats).

What you can do:

- upgrade to a newer LibreOffice version that may or may not have improved PPT support:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-2
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt full-upgrade
  ```
- Convert the PPT file to PPTX with Microsoft Office because the latter is better supported by LibreOffice overall.